# how to parse csv-like definition and build dependency set from shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

Consider a definitions of *roles*, where each line is either empty, a comment (prefixed with hash sign) or a role definitions. A role definitions consists of a name followed by a colon and none, one or multiple, space-separated role dependencies:

```
# this is a comment

somerole: role2 role3
role2: role3
# 'empty' roles should be supported as well
roled:
anotherrole: somerole role2
```

I want to get all dependent roles in a bash function in a way I can iterate over them. They need to be listed only once and in the right order, e.g. if role1 depends on role2, and role2 depends on role3, the order need to be *role3, role2, role1*, not *role1, role2, role3*. The definition file is guaranteed to not contain any circular dependencies.

I can parse the role file (quite naively, for sure) by iterating over each entry like

```
for role in $(cat "$ROLEFILE" |grep -v -e '^$' -e '#'); do
    # test if name ends with colon
    echo $role|grep -qe ':$'
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        # remove last character
        role=$(echo $role|sed 's/.$//')
        echo "new role definition: $role"
    else
        echo "role depenency: $role"
    fi
done
```

But how can I build unique sets of dependencies, and *collect* the dependencies for a given input role?

This is how an example invocation could look like. Each dependency need to be printed before the role which depends on it. The final role is always the role we've asked for.

```
$ ./testroles somerole
role3 role2 somerole
$ ./testroles roled
roled
$ ./testroles anotherrole
role3 role2 somerole anotherrole
```

The resulting script should work with Ubuntu 14.04 and OS X.

Comment: Implementing this as a shell script will be both hard to do and run slowly, though perhaps `awk` is an option; alternatively, consider using Python (2.x), which is preinstalled on both platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created the script bellow, it prints the dependency tree just like you described. It uses [shell_map](https://github.com/bnegrao/shell_map/blob/master/shell_map.sh) to create a Map of roles-dependencies.

```
#!/bin/bash
source shell_map.sh

ROLE_ARG="$1"
ROLEFILE=input.sh

# create a new map where roles are keys and deps are values
shell_map new roles_map

while read line; do 
    #skip comments
    [[ $line =~ ^#.*$ ]] && continue;

    #skip blank lines
    [[ "$line" =~ ^[[:alpha:]]+ ]] || continue;

    deps=$(echo $line | cut -d ":" -f2)
    role=$(echo $line | cut -d ":" -f1)

    # put in the map
    roles_map put $role "$deps"
done < $ROLEFILE

# this map will store the dependency tree without repetitions
shell_map new deps_tree

function role_deps {
    local role=$1
    local my_deps=`roles_map get $role`

    [ -z "$my_deps" ] && return 0

    for dep in $my_deps; do
        deps_tree put $dep ""
        for inherited_dep in `role_deps $dep`; do
            deps_tree put $inherited_dep ""
        done;
    done

    # echoes the dependencies stored in the map
    deps_tree keys
}

echo `role_deps $ROLE_ARG` $ROLE_ARG
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't parse the file line by line??

```
while read line; do 
  dep=$(echo $line | cut -d ":" -f2)
  role=$(echo $line | cut -d ":" -f1)
  echo "$dep $role"
  # or do anything you want...  
done < $ROLEFILE
```

Comment: You code does not skip comments and blank lines, but this should be easy to add. It's nice and clean, but does not solve my actual problem, which is processing the retrieved data

Comment: Maybe don't understand you, but you can nest "if" to exclude this types of lines:
For example: if [ -z $line ] (empty line)